# How would you implement a caching aspect in Scala

Tags: scala, caching, aop, python-decorators

*Brainstorming*: I am working on a Scala project where we do service calls and need to cache the return values using memcache. I was working on a Python project that [used decorators](http://www.planetframework.com/documentation/1.10/Developing/Caching-and-optimizations/) to annotate the functions whose return values should be cached. I am looking for a similar way in Scala to add a caching aspect to a function.

Lets say I have this function `def callingService(arg1: String, arg2: Int): String` I want to

- compute a cache key based on the function name and arguments
- if the cache doesn't contain the key do the service call
- serialize the return value and store it in the cache
- otherwise deserialize the cached value and return it

Any code that invokes callingService should not know about caching. The implementation of callingService should just call service X and return a String value and not deal with caching stuff.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer Stackable Trait Pattern and Cake Pattern for that:

```
class Service {
  def callingService(arg1: String, arg2: Int): String = "ok"
}

trait Memo[K, V] {
  def cache(k: K)(v : => V): V
}

trait ServiceCache extends Service {
  self : Memo[(String, Int), String] =>

  abstract override def callingService(arg1: String, arg2: Int): String =
    cache((arg1, arg2)) { super.callingService(arg1, arg2) }
}

trait MapCache[K, V] extends Memo[K, V] {
  private val _cache = new collection.mutable.HashMap[K, V]
  def cache(k: K)(v : => V): V = _cache.getOrElseUpdate(k, v)
}
```

using example:

```
val service = new Service with ServiceCache with MapCache[(String, Int), String]
```

and of course you can implement own Caching strategy and mix with it at the moment of service creation

Comment: Be aware that cake pattern can introduce too much of boilterplate and may end up being one of those tough to maintain patterns. I came across a similar situation recently where eventually had to get away with cake pattern. May be Reader monad can be a better alternative or implicits. Odersky declared implicits is his choice after experimenting with other alternatives. check this : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-user/n50RW4gQBS4/lqkaTKjxb2gJ

Answer (score 2):

scalaz provides a nice cache implementation: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day16

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do this automatically in Scala. I think you would do it yourself.

You want any calling code to know about the cache. I think the only way to do that would be to have the caching mechanism inside the function itself.

Why don't you use a closure:

```
val cachedFunc = {
  val cache = mutable.Map[Int, Double]()

  def internalFunc(y: Int) : Double = Math.sqrt(y);

  (y: Int) => {
    if (cache.keySet.contains(y))
      cache(y)
    else
    {
      val result = internalFunc(y);
      cache += y -> result;
      result
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can:

```
cachedFunc(200)
```